# How to make the same material sidenav behavior in angular 8?

Tags: angular, typescript, material-design

When I load the page with the [sidenav](https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/overview) component, the menu on the left is closed. How to make the menu open by default and only after reducing the window width, did the burger button appear and the menu itself collapsed?
I want to do the same https://material.angular.io/components/categories

I crate new component use that command:

```
ng generate @angular/material:nav <component-name>
```

(https://material.angular.io/guide/schematics)

**navigation.component.html**

```
<mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container">
  <mat-sidenav #drawer class="sidenav" fixedInViewport
      [attr.role]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'dialog' : 'navigation'"
      [mode]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'over' : 'side'"
      [opened]="(isHandset$ | async) === false">
    <mat-toolbar>Menu</mat-toolbar>
    <mat-nav-list>
      <a mat-list-item href="/about">About</a>
      <a mat-list-item href="/contact">Contact</a>
    </mat-nav-list>
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content>
    <mat-toolbar color="primary">
      <button
        type="button"
        aria-label="Toggle sidenav"
        mat-icon-button
        (click)="drawer.toggle()"
        *ngIf="isHandset$ | async">
        <mat-icon aria-label="Side nav toggle icon">menu</mat-icon>
      </button>
      <span>NavApp</span>
    </mat-toolbar>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <!-- Add Content Here -->
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

**navigation.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { BreakpointObserver, Breakpoints } from '@angular/cdk/layout';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map, share } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navigation',
  templateUrl: './navigation.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navigation.component.scss']
})
export class NavigationComponent {

  isHandset$: Observable<boolean> = this.breakpointObserver.observe(Breakpoints.Handset)
    .pipe(
      map(result => result.matches),
      share()
    );

  constructor(private breakpointObserver: BreakpointObserver) {}

}
```

when i try change [opened]="true" left menu is opened, but no event binding for this.breakpointObserver.observe(Breakpoints.Handset) and if i resize window left menu not closed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem you have is that in your component you are using the `share()` operator to share the observable from `this.breakpointObserver.observe()` among the four subscribers (async pipe) in your HTML template.

This means that this observable will emit when it is *first* subscribed to (in the `<mat-sidenav>` element); this emission will be shared, but as your `<button>` element has *not yet been created*, the emission is too early and the `<button>` will never receive it. This means that the `*ngIf` on the button will evaluate to false on first load, even if `isHandset$` has actually emitted true, so you will not see the menu button on mobile view.

To solve this you can use the `shareReplay()` operator instead of `share()`, which will replay the emission from `this.breakpointObserver.observe()` to all new subscribers (e.g. the one in `<button>`), even if they have been created after the emission.

**navigation.component.ts**

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { BreakpointObserver, Breakpoints } from '@angular/cdk/layout';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map, shareReplay } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-navigation',
    templateUrl: './navigation.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./navigation.component.scss']
})
export class NavigationComponent {
    isHandset$: Observable<boolean> = this.breakpointObserver.observe(Breakpoints.Handset)
        .pipe(
            map(result => result.matches),
            shareReplay(1),
        );

    constructor(private breakpointObserver: BreakpointObserver) { }
}
```

Comment: can please explain more, it real works, but i don't understand why

Comment: @redk0m I realised the solution I gave wasn't very good, so I've now updated my answer with a better solution with explanation. My original answer worked in a similar way to the new one (ensuring all subscribers in your template received the observable) but as you see in my new solution, it was unnecessary to create separate subscriptions for each async pipe in the template.

Answer (score 0):

To perhaps add to this, in case someone is looking to observe a change on a specific width, replace the breakpointObserver.observe code with this:

```
     isHandset$: Observable<boolean> = this.breakpointObserver.observe('(max-width: 720px)')
        .pipe(
            map(result => result.matches),
            shareReplay(1),
        );
```